# Running lilypond for each .ly file in a directory

Tags: perl

I know I could grovel through the Perl docs and write this, but I suspect there's an easy one-liner to do exactly what I want, and that would take me too long to figure out.

I have a main .ly file for a piece of music, and a set of smaller .ly files to generate the parts and the conductor's score.

So, what I want to do is basically this:

```
for each file in directory
   if filename ends in ".ly"
      lilypond filename
   endif
endfor
```

Thanks to Similar Questions, I just found the .BAT answer for this, but I'd like to know how to do it in Perl for the next time around. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq and show us WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED

Comment: To answer the "What have you tried" question -- not much. The searching I did didn't give me a clear enough answer on how to grovel through a directory, which was why I came here.

Comment: "I suspect there's an easy one-liner to do exactly what I want, and that would take me too long to figure out." This should be a new close reason...

Comment: Flimzy - Translated, that would be "I sort of speak Perl, and could probably write a long program to do this, but given what I know of Perl, I'm sure that there's an idiomatically simple way to do it, even though my searches in the help file haven't yet gotten me there." I just said it more tersely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use autodie qw( :all );
opendir(my $dh, $dir_qfn);
while (defined( my $file = readdir($dh) )) {
   system('lilypond', "$dir_qfn\\$file")
      if $file =~ /\.ly\z/i;
}
```